# Running GWTTestCase on Already Compiled Module

Tags: optimization, gwt, junit, tdd

I have an automated build script which involves unit testing of some GWT Modules in production mode.  It appears that when these tests are run, they recompile the GWT module.

However, earlier in the build script, I have already compiled the modules.  This is an obvious waste of effort.  Does anybody know of any way to test a GWTTestCase to run in production mode, on modules that were already compiled.

I don't mind losing stacktraces or any information, because the build server only informs developers of which tests fails, and expects them to debug in their own environment.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful for you

The main class in the test infrastructure is **JUnitShell**. To control aspects of how your tests execute, you must pass arguments to this class. Arguments cannot be passed directly through the command-line because normal command-line arguments go directly to the JUnit runner. Instead, define the system property gwt.args to pass arguments to JUnitShell.

**For example, to run tests in production mode** (that is, run the tests afer they have been compiled into JavaScript), declare -Dgwt.args="-prod" as a JVM argument when invoking JUnit. To get a full list of supported options, declare -Dgwt.args="-help" (instead of running the test, help is printed to the console).
Running your test in Production Mode

When using the webAppCreator tool, you get the ability to launch your tests in either development mode or production mode. Make sure you test in both modes - although rare, there are some differences between Java and JavaScript that could cause your code to produce different results when deployed.

If you instead decide to run the **JUnit TestRunner** from command line, you must add some additional arguments to get your unit tests running in production mode. By default, tests run in development mode are run as normal Java bytecode in a JVM. To override this default behavior, you need to pass arguments to JUnitShell

**-Dgwt.args="-prod"**

Comment: I know how to run it on production code, the problem is that this recompiles the project, when I've already done that.  I want to point it to code that I've already compiled...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, but it is not elagant. I modified `JUnitShell.maybeCompileForWebMode` method, you should add  VM argument `-Dcompile=false`  to prevent compilation while running unit tests . You can get modified version of JUnitShell from [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B8sSS_DN3oWnMmM5OGE1MzctNWQxNy00NzkwLWE2NzgtMTc5NzA5NDc0MTZm&hl=en&authkey=CMO6yYcC) .